# Periodically calling a function since system initialization

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

Assume I have a per-CPU variable declared with `DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct var, var)` and associated to each `struct var` is an attribute `int count`. This occurs during system initialization and is therefore (assumedly) located in `init/main.c`. Further assume that I have an `increment_count()` function defined as

```
    void increment_count() {
        per_cpu(var, get_cpu()).count += 1;
        put_cpu();
    }
```

I would like for `increment_count` to get called by the kernel every `x` milliseconds, beginning at system initialization. Some jitter in the timing interval is fine. How can this be implemented in practice? Furthermore, do I need to explicitly preempt the currently running thread to allow the `increment_count()` thread to run?